# Does meta prune poorly-received posts more often?

Tags: discussion, meta, automatic-deletion

A few months ago (I think), I made a meta post asking if [trackball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trackball) should be burned. The consensus was "no", and I believe the post sat at -4 when last I saw it.

Yesterday I stumbled back onto the tag and decided that if it wouldn't burn, I would at least try editing the wiki to make it more accessible. I looked for the meta post I'd made to see if there was anything worth using in it, but it appears to have been removed, and I'm assuming it's too old to appear in "deleted recent questions".

Given that I've seen a couple questions on SO with negative scores that are still around, I'm left wondering, does meta prune its poorly-received posts more often than main?

Comment: Link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390535/ambiguous-tag-trackball

Comment: Thank you, off to the tag wiki I go!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

The [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) works the same on main and meta.

However, since on meta posts often get more votes and less answers, the odds of writing a question that meets the roomba criteria is substantially higher.

<sup>Too lazy to write a SEDE query atm, but 99.9% sure it's true</sup>

Comment: Also, there is substantially less traffic on meta, and a higher ratio of users casting their votes (of all kinds, delete-votes included).

Comment: ...and there is a higher incidence of moderator traffic on Meta, which *does* result in garbage questions being pruned more often. I personally delete many of them on Meta.

Comment: I doubt that is accurate.  Best way to avoid the little sucker is to get an answer.  [discussion] is 80% answered last month, [support] is 79%.  More likely are the large number of questions voluntarily withdrawn by their authors.

Comment: On non-Meta sites, the roomba will remove zero-score questions with little activity after a year. These removals do not take place on Metas though.